# How can i change the color of a cell in Windows Excel based on the color of another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to change the color of multiple cells, based on the color of the cell to the left of them: for example: When A2 is red, I want B2 and C2 to adopt the same color.

I cannot find any formulas in conditional formatting for this. I'm inexperienced with the VBA Editor.

Comment: There is no way to do that with conditional formatting. You either need to use VBA or change logic how your workbook works

Comment: The question is what colors A2?  Is it manually done or done by another conditional formatting rule?

Comment: how is the color applied to A2? Manually: then the first comment is the answer, by conditional formatting: then you re-use the same rules for B2 and C2